# Performance of .something :first-child as a selector?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Is the following selector likely to have performance issues?

```
.div-class :first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Ive read that using the * selector within another selector is slow. Presumably the above is effectively the same as this?

```
.div-class *:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

This is for a mobile website which I image would exaggerate any issue.

UPDATE - I think ive been unclear in what im asking. Im wondering if these selectors are bad for performance?

Comment: I would imagine that *:first-child would be slow due to * but if you are just targeting first-child of whatever item, it should be fine

Comment: What used to be slow, if I remember correctly, is `*` coupled with the direct descendant selector, like so: `.header > *`. "Used to" because selector performance is apparently not a big issue anymore, but `layout` and `paint` operations are. Visit Chromium's http://jankfree.org/ for more info about on-page performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are functionally equivalent. The cost of adding the `*` character itself should be almost nothing since you're just explicitly specifying something that's otherwise implied anyway.

As for whether `*:first-child` is slow, there is no definitive answer — it depends not only on your layout, but also, heavily, on external factors outside of your control, including both hardware capabilities and browser implementations. Your best bet will be in running your own benchmarks where possible.

Personally, I would avoid worrying about it until I can determine that it's where the bottleneck is occurring.

One thing I can suggest (but not guarantee that it will help) is that if `.div-class` will only ever have one level of descendants, you can replace the descendant combinator with the direct descendant combinator:

```
.div-class > :first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

This restricts lookup to immediate ancestors, so the browser only has to decide whether or not each first child's parent is `.div-class`, and does not have to continue looking at further ancestors. This will help with elements that are outside of any `.div-class` hierarchies entirely.

Again, this assumes a naïve implementation of descendant and child combinators, and so I can't guarantee that it will actually improve rendering performance. But, depending on your layout, it may be worth a try.

Comment: @jdln: I can't say for sure - it depends on *a lot* of factors including both hardware and software. Your best bet will be in running your own benchmarks.